# Does a Rails app handle CSS differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css

I have two sets of identical html and css files. One of which I'm loading up through Rails' index.html.erb file via a controller and all that, the other I'm running through my public folder as a control. The public index.html file looks fine:

[image: Index in public directory]

But when I run these exact same files in the rails index.html.erb file, it looks like this:

[image: index.html.erb file]

As you might be able to notice, the BETA text is slightly lower in the Rails build, and obviously the navigation list goes below my header element.

I'm admittedly a bit new at both css and rails, so this may be a known issue I'm unaware of. I tried searching for some insight but didn't find any problems similar to this one. If anyone has a tip on how to resolve this I'd be very thankful!

EDIT: I'm including my index.html and style.css files in the following pastebins. They're quite small, maybe a look at them could give some insight to you guys.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/wyYEN92n

CSS: http://pastebin.com/60xMe9YG

EDIT 2:

Found these two lines in the page source:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I'm thinking it is safe to assume that something in these css files is causing the discrepancy. I will investigate and report back.

EDIT 3:

Looks like neither of those css files actually do anything. I'm including the contents of both in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pbHwEp4w

As you can see it's just commented stuff. What I did notice however, is that the page source has 2 html tags included in the same file. I'm pastebining that as well: http://pastebin.com/h4Rjqi4B

It goes

```
<html>//rails generated stuff</html> 
<html>//My stuff</html>
```

Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to edit #3: it looks like that is coming from the default layout in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. By default, Rails will load that file and put all of the content from the view where <%= yield %> is specified. If you had additional <html>, <head>, etc. tags in your view file, they would be duplicated. You can learn more about layouts [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield). Also, take a look at the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for how to structure your CSS files in the app.

Like Ernest said, Rails is just delivering the HTML/CSS files, so the framework itself does not affect how the browser renders the content. However, the *order* in which the content is presented to the browser, of course, does matter.

Comment: I added the css file to the assets pipeline rather than public/stylesheets and the problem was solved. I won't question too deeply, just be grateful at this point lol

Answer (score 2):

CSS is interpreted in the browser, not on the server, so the easy answer is "no". But your styles could possibly be interpreted differently when they're added to any styles included in the Rails app itself, and possibly your HTML might be a bit different between the two. Examine the CSS included in the Rails app and take out anything that's going to adversely affect your design -- or simply remove all of it, making sure your CSS file is the only one in the whole codebase.

Comment: The html files are 100% identical, and the css file is the one included in the project. It's a direct copy and paste between the two, the only difference is one is named index.html and the other is named index.html.erb

Comment: And there's no other CSS file? If you use "view source" in the browser, has Rails inserted a link to another one into the HTML?

Comment: Ah! Looks like I found something. I'm going to add it to the question for readability.

Comment: Try to dig through Firebug or Chrome tools to see "inherited styles". Sometimes there maybe something that the element(s) is/are inheriting from another CSS.

Comment: Found two rails generated css files that were sticking their nose in my business here, I will update the question when I find out what if anything they are affecting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this kind of problem: INSPECT.

Use your browser's inspector to check which CSS rules are affecting a given element.
So, let's say you use Google Chrome, you can:

1. Right click one of your navigation bar items, select **Inspect Element**
2. Then in the new source code window select either **.logo-container** or **.nav**
3. Check the panel on the right: You'll see all the currently applied CSS rules for that element.
4. You'll also see which file is applying which rule.
5. ???
6. PROFIT!